# How many such rearrangements are.

Tags: combinatorics

The 5 letters in the list G, H, I, J, K are to be rearranged so that G is the 3rd letter in the list and  H is not next to G. How many such rearrangements are.

Let there are 5 positions  * * * * *

We have fixed the  3rd place for G, therefore * * G * *

- 1st pace can be rearranged by 4 ways.
- 2nd pace can be rearranged by 2 ways.[because H can not be placed there.]
- 4th  pace can be rearranged by 1 ways.[because H can not be placed there.]
- 5th  pace can be rearranged by 2 ways. 
  So the total number of ways are = $4 \times 2 \times 2 =16$

But the answer is given 12.

Where did I do wrong

Comment: First place can only be arranged 3 ways if H is not there (and which case H is in 5th place). You have 2 possibilities H*G** and **G*H which add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your analysis is that the $4$ ways that the first place can be filled are of *two different types*. If we fill with an H, then the remaining $3$ slots can be filled in $3!$ ways.

For the other $3$ ways of filling the first place, we must place the H in fifth place. Then the remaining two slots can be filled in $2!$ ways, giving $(3)(2!)$.

Now add the contributions from the two types.

**Remark:** As has been pointed out elsewhere, it is often more efficient to take care of fussy people like H first. That way, we don't end up with two different types.

If for **each** of the $a$ ways of carrying out Task 1, there are $b$ ways to carry out Task 2, then Tasks 1 and 2 can be dine in $ab$ ways. But if you cannot use the word "each" then multiplication is not the appropriate tool.

In filling the last place using your method, we certainly do not have $2$ ways to fill fifth place for *each* of the legal ways of filling the first four places.

Answer (score 0):

$G$ is not free, $H$ can only be at $1$ or at $5$, giving $2$ choices. The remaining $3$ letters can be arranged in any way in the remaining $3$ spaces, giving $3!$, thus
$$N = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3! = 2\cdot 6 = 12$$

Answer (score 0):

Always arrange those entities first which are restricted. This will allow up for filling spaces later on with other entities. In this case, after fixing G in the 3rd place,  fill up H, which clearly can be done in 2 ways (1st and last position)
Thus, for H, we have 2 ways. Then there are no restrictions left. We have 3 places left and 3 letters, and we can arrange the remaining letters in 3! ways (permuting 3 objects).

**Thus total number of ways is = 2 * 3! = (2 * 6) = 12**

You may have different cases: if you are placing H at first position, then 4th and 2nd are not restricted. **But you are handling it all at once. The fallacy in your argument is suppose H is in the first position (because you have done it in 4 possible ways), then 2nd position will have of a choice of 3, and 4th will have a choice of 2.**

Same for when H is in the last position.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to think about it:

You'll ram $G$ into the middle at the end, so just arrange the four remaining letters in $4!$ (or 24) ways.

In all of these arrangements, H is paired with another letter either before or after the $G$ slot.

In exactly half of these arrangements, the $H$ is adjacent to the $G$, so the acceptable arrangements number half of $24$, or $12$